# Having issue in changing style through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, styles, custom-data-attribute

Hi i am trying to change Display property of any HTML Tag with certain attribute..
But after many tries i am unable to change the tag properties.. My code is as below

```
function getAllElementsWithAttribute(attribute)
{
  var matchingElements = [];
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++)
  {
    if (allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute))
    {
      // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
      matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
    }
  }
  return matchingElements;
}
tags = getAllElementsWithAttribute('data-shares');
for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
{
    tags[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

And the HTML has below Tag

```
<div  class="shareTools" data-shares="facebook" data-url="#" data-title="Facebook" data-description="Facebook">
    <div class="shareToolsBox">
        <ul class="shareToolsList">
            <li data-share="facebook">
                <span>Facebook</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone has any idea how to change Tag Style of any tag which has attribut i-e data-shares...

Comment: I highly recommend that you look into jQuery or an alternative to perform such actions (if the project allows this). jQuery brings cross browser compatibility to delicate things like this that don't necessarily work 100% the same between say Firefox and IE.

Comment: Are the extra commas there on purpose? `tags = getAllElementsWithAttribute(,,'data-shares',);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function call to:

```
tags = getAllElementsWithAttribute('data-shares');
```

Here's it working on a JS Bin demo: http://jsbin.com/ufogExo/1/ The `<div>`s with the `data-shares` attribute are all hidden.

The problem was indeed the extra commas you had on your function call arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want:

```
function getAllElementsWithAttribute(attribute)
{
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('['+attribute+']'),
    i = items.length;
      while ( i-- > 0 && (items[i].style.display = 'none') );
}

getAllElementsWithAttribute('data-shares');
```

see
http://jsfiddle.net/754zR/